# Terminal and software update do not open anymore ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

My terminal does not open anymore. I'm using PyCharm terminal to run the commands.

I have tried so many solutions but still getting this error after running `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.192.30.5) ...

Progress: [  0%] [...........................................................................................................................................................................................................] 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/update-notifier-common.postinst: 29: /usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader: not found..........................................................................................................] 
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 installed update-notifier-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier:
 update-notifier depends on update-notifier-common (= 3.192.30.5); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
 update-manager depends on update-notifier; however:
  Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on update-manager; however:
  Package update-manager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                 Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 update-notifier
 update-manager
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas on how can I fix this, please?

Comment: The problem seems to be a missing file in the package, which is weird. Try: Delete the `update-notifier-common` package from your cache to force the system to re-download it. `sudo apt clean update-notifier-common` then `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Have you installed a version of Python 3 that is different from the default version recently?